# Can't find variable Page_ClientValidate in Safari

Tags: javascript, asp.net, safari

I have a ASP.NET 2.0 webpage with 3 server controls: `RequiredFieldValidator`, `textbox`, and `button`.`

Button uses `OnClientClick` to call a JavaScript function for validation using `Page_ClientValidate()`.

This page works fine with Chrome, IE, Firefox, Safari (5.1.7 on Windows). It has stopped working with modern Safari versions - 8.0 in Yosemite and Mobile Safari on iOS 8.

I see this exception in the Inspect Element area:

> "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Page_ClientValidate"

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a duplicate of this problem:

[iOS 8 / Safari 8 not working with ASP.NET AJAX-Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25978746/ios-8-safari-8-not-working-with-asp-net-ajax-extensions#25979199)

Another solution that modifies the web.config instead of the mozill:
[ReferenceError: Can't find variable: ValidatorEnable in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26224314/referenceerror-cant-find-variable-validatorenable-in-safari/26386806#26386806)