# Sharepoint 2010 all controls disabled

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've got Sharepoint 2010 site which has been successful for 3 years, but what happend is that all controls has been disabled even for admin account. Please have a look on screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mssHx.jpg

I tried to look for any settings for it but nothing found.

Comment: Ok, problem solved. Thank you for all sugestions. For future if someone will expierence smilar issue. Administrator set the database to read-only mode.

Answer (score 0):

Possible cause:

1. Mixed version on Office installed on client machine (x86 and x64 and/or 2010 and 2013)
2. x86 version on client machine and x64 on Sharepoint or viceversa
3. Javascript errors and/or Browser support (IE version, etc)
4. Browser plugins
5. Missing Office library
6. Permissions
7. IE launch x64 bit

Check:

Browser console,
EventViewer,
Sharepoint log (ULS log)

for any error

Try different browser, and different users (ensure permissions) and different client machine with different office version.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this could be a  web browser incompatibility, or possibly a javascript error stopping the items in the ribbon from being enabled.  It might be worth checking access using Internet Explorer.

Also useful to check for any javascript errors during the page load - which could prevent the menu from being rendered properly and the icons being enabled, or looking for other error messages information in the web browser development tools console.

I have recently seen similar problems with disabled toolbar in SharePoint 2010 when browsing using Safari 7.0+ on OS X.  Some icons in the toolbar remained disabled when Safari was upgraded to Safari 7.0/7.1 on OS X, and several AJAX features stopped working.

A workaround for an individual user using Safari could be to use the Safari developer menu to send a different 'browser user agent'.  See 'enable developer tools' in Safari preferences.

For a server side fix - look at this answer to 'iOS 8 / Safari 8 not working with ASP.NET AJAX-Extensions'.  The ribbon in Sharepoint uses 'ASPMenu' from the .NET framework, and some functionality can be restored with an update by fixing the way that .NET recognizes browser capabilities by an extra custom .browser file alongside the existing compat.browser file.

#### For a more complete server side solution - fixing the browser compatibility, see also

> [iOS 8 / Safari 8 not working with ASP.NET AJAX-Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25978746/ios-8-safari-8-not-working-with-asp-net-ajax-extensions/25979199#25979199)