# iOS 8.3 Ajax not working in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: jquery, ios, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.Net MVC 4 application and use Ajax extensively to implement usage of the application.  We have verified that our Ajax calls are not working on iOS 8.3. We have verified they work on versions before that.
I have looked online and tried the feedback posted on this question with no luck.
[iOS 8 / Safari 8 not working with ASP.NET AJAX-Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25978746/ios-8-safari-8-not-working-with-asp-net-ajax-extensions)

I tried adding the app_browser file though it states it is for framework 2.0 only and also did the web.config update but no luck. 
I am not sure where else to look. Has anybody encountered this or have any ideas?
I am in the process of trying to get more information but thought I'd get this out there in case somebody else has come across this.

Greatly appreciate and feedback.