# Sharepoint 2013 site NTLM authentication javascript doPostBack doesnt work in Safari&iPad

Tags: ipad, sharepoint, safari, ntlm, dopostback

I have a really interesting problem. We have a site created with sharepoint 2013. We use Windows - NTLM authentication.

In a page includes custom discussionListWebPart, we have a filter button which use javascript doPostBack function with **webpart ClientID** and **filter** parameters.

exp: __doPostBack("ClientID","params");

When we do filter, just discussion list webpart do post back and no any request for the any part of Page. That means the page does not reload. This is what we expected.

It works fine in the IE 10 and chrome. Whatsmore, we have problem when we open this page in any ipad. The filter button which we use __doPostBack reloads the page. Also have problem in safari on desktop.

--I controlled the IIS (8) windows authentication providers, there is just NTLM (No negatiate).

-- I found another discussion [iOS 8 / Safari 8 not working with ASP.NET AJAX-Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25978746/ios-8-safari-8-not-working-with-asp-net-ajax-extensions).

**When I open the site in safari everytime it asks for user credentials. If I say remember password doPostBack works fine.**

But I can not do this in ipad. So The problem still exists.

I dont see any console error in dvl tool. But It does not do postBack. Just refresh the page.

Please help to solve this problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem isn't with the postback, I think the problem is iOS has limited (no?) support for NTLM. A quick search shows me a whole mess of people who have encountered this issue and addressed it in different ways:

1. [Extend your SharePoint web application into an alternate zone](https://sharepointwinter.wordpress.com/2014/10/29/ios-devices-ntlm-sharepoint-2013/)
2. [Write an iOS app to handle the authentication manually for you](http://waynehartman.com/posts/how-to-do-ntlm-authentication-in-ios.html)
3. [Change the authentication on the SharePoint site to ADFS or something more iOS-friendly](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/146808/ios-8-safari-sharepoint-2013-windows-authentication-support)

None of these are the silver bullet your looking for, and they all involve you changing much more than just the code on your web site, but hopefully it'll point you in the right direction in the event there's no "easy button."

Edit: Grammar

Comment: Because of being radical , I can not do any changes with authentication method, I am confused about the reason of being worked successfully with "remember me" while entering user credentials at the first time. That means it can be done with caching  user credentials. But how? I dont know

Comment: Did it work on your iPad when saying "remember me"? I understood your question to say that you got a workaround on Safari when _not_ on an iPad because you said `But I can not do this in ipad. So The problem still exists.` Safari on a non-iOS device is _not_ the same as Safari on iOS.

Comment: The engine is same but versions are different. Thanks jcwilbur. The problem still exists. Any other help?