# Layout issue in Safari 7.1 and 8

Tags: sharepoint, browser, safari, menubar, safari7

I have a simple SharePoint Web Application which have no issue or bug, until a client open it in Safari browser version 7.1 on Mac OS 10.9 Mavericks a month ago.

Since I don't have any Mac OS, then I tried to open the web via browser emulator in http://www.browserstack.com/ and found that the problem is only happen in Safari 7.1 and 8 (no matter what the device, MacOS, iPad, or iPhone6)

When we open it using Google Chrome, Firefox, IE any version, even Safari 6 or older, it looks okay.

But when we open it using Safari 7.1 or later, the menu bar looks like wrecked.

Is anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I've did deep research and found the main problem. It's not about the layout code, but the problem is compatibility between my old SharePoint 2007/2010 with the new Safari browser 7.1 or later.

The problem fixed by this thread:
[ASPMenu in Safari 7.1 Not Rendering Properly in SharePoint 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25936427/aspmenu-in-safari-7-1-not-rendering-properly-in-sharepoint-2010)